# How to manage customer's usage-based subscription programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Let me first describe a "manual" scenario. I login to Partner Center as a partner and go to customer list (https://partnercenter.microsoft.com/en-us/pcv/customers/list). For any customer it is possible to manage all its usage-based subscriptions in Azure portal using `All resources (Azure portal)` link:

[image]

In particular, I can add a co-admin to subscription (i.e. add a user with role `Owner`):

[image]

How to automate this management of customer's subscriptions?

My efforts: I have some experience of CREST API and [RBAC API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest/). This is  limitation of an Azure Active Directory (AAD) application described in [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/):

> You can only grant access to resource in your subscription for applications in the **same** directory as your subscription.

Due to each customer's subscription exists in separate customer's AAD, it seems RBAC API cann't help:

1. It requires an AAD application-based token (i.e. based on `TenantId`,
   `ClientId`, `ClientSecret`), and there is no way to
   programmatically create an AAD application in **customer**'s directory.
2. An application located in **partner**'s AAD cann't get access to
   **customer**'s subscription.

Does any way to programmatically add an admin/co-admin/owner to customer's subscription exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Patrick Liang [help](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35e3cc88-cde9-4fd5-b639-7c9341e5c078/how-to-manage-customers-usagebased-subscription-programmatically) on MSDN forums, finally I've come up with a solution: enable `Pre-consent` feature for a partner's AAD app to grant access to customers subscriptions. Let me describe it:

**1. Partner Center Explorer project**

https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-Explorer/

It's a web application similar to [partnercenter.microsoft.com](http://partnercenter.microsoft.com)  and it's a good example of various Microsoft APIs usage. Most important, this project is a complete example of accessing customer's subscription from partner AAD app. However, it suggests user interaction (OAuth authentification to login.live.com as a partner) and I faced some issues when tried to avoid it. Below I describe how to connect to customer's subscription with all credentials already in code.

**2. Partner AAD app**

Create **native** AAD app instead of web AAD app but configure its "Permissions to other applications" the same way. **Skip** steps which are not applicable to native app (for example, skip `client_secret` obtaining and skip manifest update).

**3. PowerShell script**

Last step of app configuring is to run this script:

```
Connect-MsolService
$g = Get-MsolGroup | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq 'AdminAgents'} 
$s = Get-MsolServicePrincipal | ? {$_.AppPrincipalId -eq 'INSERT-CLIENT-ID-HERE'}
Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $g.ObjectId -GroupMemberType ServicePrincipal -GroupMemberObjectId $s.ObjectId
```

It's required to install several modules to execute these comandlets. If you get an error during "Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals" install, try to install BETA module:

[Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals BETA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39267)

And you probably will need this one:

[Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell 64-bit](http://g.microsoftonline.com/0BX10EN/423)

**4. Code**

Finally we are ready to authenticate and [create a role assignment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest/#create-a-role-assignment):

```
public async void AssignRoleAsync()
{
    var token = await GetTokenAsync();

    var response = await AssignRoleAsync(token.AccessToken);
}

public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenAsync()
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{CustomerId}");

    return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "https://management.core.windows.net/"
        , ApplicationId
        , new UserCredential(PartnerUserName, PartnerPassword));
}


public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AssignRoleAsync(string accessToken)
{
    string newAssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string subSegment = $"subscriptions/{CustomerSubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization";
    string requestUri = $"https://management.azure.com/{subSegment}/roleAssignments/{newAssignmentId}?api-version=2015-07-01";
    string roleDefinitionId = "INSERT_ROLE_GUID_HERE";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        var body = new AssignRoleRequestBody();
        body.properties.principalId = UserToAssignId;
        body.properties.roleDefinitionId = $"/{subSegment}/roleDefinitions/{roleDefinitionId}";

        var httpRequest = HttpHelper.CreateJsonRequest(body, HttpMethod.Put, requestUri);

        return await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    }
}
```

To obtain role definition IDs, just make a request to [get all roles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest/#list-all-roles) per subscription scope.

Useful links:

[MSDN: How to manage customer's usage-based subscription programmatically?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35e3cc88-cde9-4fd5-b639-7c9341e5c078/how-to-manage-customers-usagebased-subscription-programmatically)

[MSDN: When will auto-stamping/implicit consent be available for CREST customers?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe6f2e1e-5831-49b0-8fe7-a47bcd207f19/when-will-autostampingimplicit-consent-be-available-for-crest-customers)

[Managing Role-Based Access Control with the REST API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-rest/)