# Assigning a user to customer's Azure subscription from code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

As a partner I log to Partner Center, select a customer with Azure subscription and go through "Service Management" > "Microsoft Azure Management Portal" link and I land in the selected customer context. From there I can assign new users and roles (namely: owner of the subscription).

I can't do it automatically with Azure Management API though. I've found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590109/how-to-manage-customers-usage-based-subscription-programmatically) and tried to implement the token acquisition (since the provided one didn't work) as follows:

```
public string GetToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string username, string password)
{
    var creds = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
    var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientId, creds).Result;

    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
```

When I try to get a token using customer's tenantId (as in response in provided link) I get an error:

> AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '[app_id]' was not found in
>   the directory [customer_tenant_id]

On the other hand, when I use my (partner) tenantId I do get a token **but** when I try to list roles in the specified azure subscription I get an error:

> The access token is from the wrong issuer
>   'https://sts.windows.net/[partnerTenantId]/'. It must match the tenant
>   'https://sts.windows.net/[customerId]/' associated with this
>   subscription. Please use the authority (URL)
>   'https://login.windows.net/[customerId]' to get the token.

I obtain roles with this:

```
public void GetRoles(string subscriptionId, string token)
{
    var uri = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?{ApiVersion}";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
}
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

**EDIT**

One step further: i've managed to get token for customer tenant (first method described above). I had to edit app manifest, changing option

> availableToOtherTenants

to value "True".

But there is another obstacle in the way. Now, when i try to use token i get:

> The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims
>   'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing
>   as application please make sure service principal is properly created
>   in the tenant.

Anyone?

Comment: The scenario you mentioned should contains this claim.  Please check whether the `oid` claim is included in the token. And the description above should not be able to get the token since the service principal is not created in the custom's tenant. Have you granted any consent for this app? I also post the steps which works well for me for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps below works well for me to list the role definitions:

1 .Register a **native app** on developer's tenant.

2 .Grant the `Windows Azure Service Management API` to the app new register

3 .Try to grant consent to the app on customer's tenant to create the service principal via code grant flow:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{customTenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectURL}&resource=https://management.azure.com/&nonce=123`

4 .Acquire the token using code grant flow( My test enviroment is enabled MFA, not able to test the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant**, but it should not same as using **code grant flow**.

```
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{customTenant}";
        string resrouce = "https://management.azure.com/";
        string clientId = "";
        string userName = "";
        string password = "";

        UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(userName,password);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);


        var result = authContext.AcquireToken(resrouce, clientId, new Uri("http://localhost"));
        accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

5 . Call the REST to list the roles

```
GET: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions?api-version=2017-05-01

authorization: bearer {accessToken}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I've got one question regarding #3: how can i grant this consent without manually entering credentials on login page. Is there a way to do it silently (e.g. passing user/pass in request)? This whole process needs to be automatic..

Comment: The consent progress is not able to skip and done automatically. However we can use the admin grant so that other organization members will not be required to give the consent after that. To grant admin consent we need to pass the `prompt` para mere with the value `admin_consent`(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)).

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.

Yet one thing still bothers me: to grant this permission one has to manually login. Is there any way to bypass that e.g by providing Authorization header?

Comment: To sum up: each time i create a new customer i need to call this url with his id? So, if i need to manually login as an admin to achieve this doesn't that mean that it can't be run automatically?

Comment: Yes. If you want to grant the consent for the organization, you need to perform the admin grant which add the parameter 'prompt=admin_consent'( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code)).

Comment: developer's tenant means the partner tenant or the customer tenant here?